# How to determine where cursor is in a string in a form element?

Tags: javascript

I have an input.

```
<input name="inputName" id="inputId" value="Hello" />
```

Lets pretend that the cursor is after the e in hello, like so:

```
He|llo
```

How can I determine the position of the cursor within that string?  Meaning, how can I make it tell me that the cursor is right after string{1} (or before string{2})?

**Edit:** Really though, my end goal is determine if the cursor is at the end of the string.  I don't need to know if its in the middle.  If it's at the end of the string, I am capturing arrow presses and will make it jump to the next form element.  If it's at the beginning or middle, then I am not making that jump to the next form element.  Jumping around on arrow presses works already, but it jumps irregardless of where the cursor is in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that does what you want without external dependencies: http://jsfiddle.net/imsky/ZH5JL/

Assuming fields #inputId and #secondField:

```
var field = document.getElementById("inputId");

function checkCaret(f) {
    if (caretPos(f) == field.value.length) {
        document.getElementById("secondField").focus();
    }
}

function caretPos(f) {
    if (f.createTextRange) {
        var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
        r.moveEnd("character", f.value.length);
        return r.text == "" ? f.value.length : f.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
    } else return f.selectionStart;
}

field.onkeyup = function() {
    checkCaret(this)
};
field.onkeydown = function() {
    checkCaret(this)
};
field.onfocus = function() {
    checkCaret(this)
};
```

Comment: I found and used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea and it worked like a charm!  Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery there is a plugin - [fieldselection](https://github.com/localhost/jquery-fieldselection). It supports start/end, selected text, etc.

Comment: For this task, and for the browser compatibility it will be better with jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is not an option, unfortunately.  Nor is prototype.

Comment: All I need is to get pointed in the write direction.  Should I be looking at Range or something else?